# Firefox on MacOS: Customize keyboard shortcut for "go back"

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to change the keyboard shortcut for the back button? Because there is no menu item for this, the MacOS keyboard shortcuts cannot be used.

Instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (boths hands needed) I want to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> (left hand only)

**Update:** With thanks to @sintax I installed Hammerspoon and wrote this little script to add the new shortcut. Works fine!

```lua
goBack = hs.hotkey.new({'cmd'}, 'escape', function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({'cmd'}, 'left')
end)

hs.window.filter.new('Firefox')
  :subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowFocused,function() goBack:enable() end)
  :subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowUnfocused,function() goBack:disable() end)
```

Comment: The wonderful BetterTouchTool will let you add shortcuts for any menu item OR keyboard shortcut, activated by keyboard shortcut, custom gesture (per application or global) or any other trigger you can think of.  I can’t praise it highly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably writing a [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) script to provide that functionality by watching for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> pressed while Firefox is foregrounded and sending a WWW_BACK keycode when it sees that. Hammerspoon is like Autohotkey, but more powerful. It's scripted in Lua, which is quite straightforward to start writing.